# Variation on Bellman-Ford Algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, shortest-path, bellman-ford

We have a Directed Graph with 100 vertexes. v1 --> v2 --> ... v100 and all edges weights is equal to 1. we want to used bellman-ford for finding all shortest paths from v1 to other vertexes. this algorithm in each step check all edges in arbitrary order. if in each step the shortest distance v1 to all others vertexes is not changed, this algorithm halt. the number of steps is related to checking order of edges. what is the minimum and maximum of steps in this problem?

Solution: 2 and 100.

How this solution will be achieved?

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/53389/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is 2 if the edges are like

```
v1->v2
v1->v3
...
```

In this case the first iteration will find the distance from source to each edge and second iteration won't change any weight and thus algorithm stops

The solution is 100, if

```
v1->v2->v3->...->v100
```

.i.e. all are in a straight line, than we need 99 iterations to update the distance to 100th vertex and the last iteration won't change the distance.

Comment: For solution in 2 case, you can prove that in 2nd iteration no distance will change, so algorithm stops. For 100th you can say that it will require at least 99 iteration to update 100th vertex from inf to correct distance and last iteration doesn't change any distance so algorithm stops. I don't know if there can be any more mathematical approach.

Comment: @coderhacker you answer is wrong ! how you say "v1->v2->v3->...->v100" need 100 steps? it just need 2 step, because each edges weights is 1.